# react correct url dom router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm creating my first react application, I can't find how to prevent the user from accessing a route that is not part of the application. Knowing that there are routes with authentication and others without authentication. I am using `react-router-dom@6` for my routes with mandatory authentication I found.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <header className="App-header">
    <Navigation />
  </header>
  <Routes>
    <Route path={"/"} element={<Accueil />} />
    <Route path={"notre-histoire"} element={<OurHistory />} />
    <Route path={"notre-savoir-faire"} element={<OurExpertise />} />
    <Route path={"l-actualite"} element={<News />} />
    <Route path={"les-patisseries/les-exclusifs"} element={<Exclusifs />} />
    <Route path={"les-patisseries/les-classiques"} element={<Classiques />} 
    <Route path={"inscription"} element={<Registration />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "prevent the user from accessing a route that is not part of the application" means specifically? If there's not a route rendering any content for a given path, nothing is "accessed" or rendered. The question and any issue is unclear.

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese for help , Yes, I mean if the url is https://mySite.fakeurl, I want if the user writes https://mySite.fakeUrl/test for example that he is redirected to a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `react-router-dom` alone you can render a "catch all" `path="*"` route that will be matched if no other route paths match the current URL path. On this route you can render any "404" content necessary.

Note that this ***not*** an HTML server redirect to a 404 page, but client-side routing.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <header className="App-header">
    <Navigation />
  </header>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Accueil />} />
    <Route path="notre-histoire" element={<OurHistory />} />
    <Route path="notre-savoir-faire" element={<OurExpertise />} />
    <Route path="l-actualite" element={<News />} />
    <Route path="les-patisseries/les-exclusifs" element={<Exclusifs />} />
    <Route path="les-patisseries/les-classiques" element={<Classiques />} 
    <Route path="inscription" element={<Registration />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<div>404</div>} /> // <-- "catch all" 404 route
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```